# Alter table, add column / ORA-00984: column not allowed here PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, alter

The next statement SQL give me a "ORA-00984: column not allowed here":

```
ALTER TABLE USUVCB.TVCB_RUT_SII ADD (Fecha_Inicio VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) DEFAULT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, "YYYY-MM-DD") NOT NULL);
```

It's into a PL-SQL, like this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
Fecha VARCHAR2(8) := TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD');
Tabla VARCHAR2(28) := 'USER.TABLE_' || Fecha;
BEGIN
    SAVEPOINT START;
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ' || Tabla || ' AS SELECT FIELD_1, FIELD_2, FIELD_3 FROM USER.TABLE';
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error creating the table');
    END;

    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE USER.TABLE ADD (FIELD_4 VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) DEFAULT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, "YYYY-MM-DD") NOT NULL)';
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error creating the field');
    END;

    BEGIN
        ...
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('...');
    END;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Rollback');
    ROLLBACK TO START;
END;
```

I would like it to catch all exceptions ocurred into PL-SQL to could rollback at check-point START in case of any error.

Comment: Why the hell do you add a `DATE` column as VARCHAR?

Comment: Transactions (i.e. `ROLLBACK`) does not help you, because **each** DDL command makes an implicit `COMMIT` at execution.

Comment: You will never reach line `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Rollback');` because all exceptions are handled previously.

Comment: String/Character values need to be put in single quotes. `"YYYY-MM-DD"` is an identifier, `'YYYY-MM-DD'` is a character constant

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I use this due to a inexplicable requirement customer.

Comment: Try to convince him that this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use single quotes for the format mask:

```
ALTER TABLE USUVCB.TVCB_RUT_SII ADD (Fecha_Inicio VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) DEFAULT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') NOT NULL);
```

In an EXECUTE, this will be:

```
execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE USUVCB.TVCB_RUT_SII ADD (Fecha_Inicio VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) DEFAULT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, ''YYYY-MM-DD'') NOT NULL)';
```

Notice that you are doing DDL queries, so you will not be able to rollback the modifications you made. A rollback only affects data, not the structure.

Besides, why do you store a date in a `varchar` column? it is a bad idea, it would be much better a `date` column

Comment: I store the date into a varchar, to could use it into the name of the backup table. Is there anyway to could rollback in case of error?

Comment: A rollback is not the way. An easy way could be to build a revert statement for each statement you execute, store them in some variable and then run them in case of error

Comment: In this case, could I catch any error ocurred into the external exception?

Comment: You could handle the exception any way you need; you could simply replace your rollback with something scanning an array of statements and running them

Comment: Into the "Execute IMMEDIATE" I can't use single quotes, due to they define the SQL. I can't to change it for double quotes, due to they don't could define the SQL. Your answer only works if I use it lonely, but into the PL-SQL doesn't works for me.

Comment: You simply have to handle the single quote in a string; just showed you the way

Comment: Also, notice the Wernfried's comment: you need to add a raise in the internal exception handling  to propagate the exception.

Comment: "I store the date into a varchar, to could use it into the name of the backup table" doesn't make any sense. You could use a `date` column just as easily.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I thinked that he means "Fecha VARCHAR2(8) := TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD');". FIELD_4 is VARCHAR2 due to a requirement customer

Answer (score 1):

Aleksej has a good solution. One often overlooked feature of Oracle is q quoting. By using this feature, you can use single quotes. Here is the same answer with q quoting:

```
EXECUTE immediate q'[ALTER TABLE USUVCB.TVCB_RUT_SII ADD (Fecha_Inicio VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) DEFAULT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') NOT NULL)]';
```

Answer (score 1):

I got my solution:

i am using

`ALTER TABLE PG_PGS_MST_LABEL  MODIFY (LANG_CODE DEFAULT EN );`

but

my solution is that Lang_CODE column is varchar2 and i have to use single codes in EN i.e,

```
ALTER TABLE PG_PGS_MST_LABEL  MODIFY (LANG_CODE DEFAULT 'EN' );
```

thanks.