# Oracle SQL error "ORA-00984: column not allowed here" when trying to replace a column

Tags: sql, oracle

This question is **not** a duplicate from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39749577/alter-table-add-column-ora-00984-column-not-allowed-here-plsql) because even if the error messages are equal the answers there do not apply to my case.

I need to change a previous PK Id column defined as `VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL` to an incremental integer value. I'm trying to write a script to do this but when I run the alter table statement it fails with the error on the title.

The table is previously defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE journal_messages(
    ID           VARCHAR(36)    NOT NULL, -- column to be changed
    MESSAGE      VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
    MESSAGE_TYPE VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    MSG_DATE     TIMESTAMP      NOT NULL,
    MODULE_CODE  INTEGER NOT NULL    
);

ALTER TABLE journal_messages ADD (CONSTRAINT journal_messages_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

The script I'm running is:

```
DELETE FROM JOURNAL_MESSAGES;

ALTER TABLE JOURNAL_MESSAGES DROP COLUMN ID;

CREATE SEQUENCE journal_messages_seq START WITH 1;

ALTER TABLE JOURNAL_MESSAGES ADD (ID NUMBER(10) DEFAULT journal_messages_seq.nextval NOT NULL); -- error happens here

ALTER TABLE journal_messages ADD (
  CONSTRAINT journal_messages_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

When I try to create a trigger it to update the incremental, it fails with `SQL Error [4098] [42000]: ORA-04098: trigger 'TRG_SEQ_JOURNAL_MSG' is invalid and failed re-validation` when I try to insert a new tuple:

```
ALTER TABLE JOURNAL_MESSAGES DROP COLUMN ID;

ALTER TABLE JOURNAL_MESSAGES ADD (ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL);

create or replace trigger trg_seq_journal_msg
      before insert on journal_messages
      for each row
    begin
      :new.id := journal_messages_seq.nextval;
    end;
    /

INSERT INTO JOURNAL_MESSAGES (message, MESSAGE_TYPE, msg_date, MODULE_CODE) VALUES ('test', 'alteration', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '10');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm ... not like that, but like this:

- once the table is empty, you don't have to drop the column - just modify its datatype
- use a trigger to automatically set IDs value

If you were on 12c, you could have used *identity* column.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE journal_messages(
  2      ID           VARCHAR(36)    NOT NULL, -- column to be changed
  3      MESSAGE      VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
  4      MESSAGE_TYPE VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  5      MSG_DATE     TIMESTAMP      NOT NULL,
  6      MODULE_CODE  INTEGER NOT NULL
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> delete from journal_Messages;

0 rows deleted.

SQL> alter table journal_messages modify (id number(10));

Table altered.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE journal_messages_seq START WITH 1;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_joumes
  2    before insert on journal_messages
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.id := journal_messages_seq.nextval;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: after reading your comment and saw your edition]**

That still works OK - I literally copy/pasted your code and got this:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE JOURNAL_MESSAGES DROP COLUMN ID;

Table altered.

SQL> ALTER TABLE JOURNAL_MESSAGES ADD (ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL);

Table altered.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_seq_journal_msg
  2        before insert on journal_messages
  3        for each row
  4      begin
  5        :new.id := journal_messages_seq.nextval;
  6      end;
  7      /

Trigger created.

SQL> INSERT INTO JOURNAL_MESSAGES (message, MESSAGE_TYPE, msg_date, MODULE_CODE) VALUES ('test', 'alteration', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '10')
  2  ;

1 row created.

SQL>
```

As you can see, everything seems to be just fine. Try the following: recompile the trigger and show errors (if any; if so, please, post them here):

```
SQL> alter trigger trg_seq_journal_msg compile;

Trigger altered.

SQL> show err
No errors.
SQL>
```

Comment: Yours maybe, mine doesn't. Please, post code you wrote so that we'd see what you did. You know, it is difficult to debug code you can't see. In order to do that, edit the original message you posted, don't post it within the comment.

Comment: Thank you; I've edited my message too. Have  a look, please.

Comment: well. the compile command runs with no error, however the other error remains... But anyway, can't I just redefine the column? is the trigger really necessary?

Comment: Which Oracle database are you using? As I've said, below 12c trigger is the only option to autoincrement column value.

Comment: `select * from v$version` returns "Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - 64bi"

Comment: So trigger it is.